# problem with the ceil function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ceil

I keep getting this error when I try to use the ceil function the error says ceil is not a function.

Below is a picture

[image]

I also tried to debug it but I don't see any error!

[image]

As you can see the cal has a value of 2.8 which should be rounded to 3 so what's the problem here?

Comment: You should post your actual code instead screenshots of the code. Otherwise its just guessing.

Comment: Check, what `Math.ceil` is at the time of the error. Set a watch in the debugger for `Math.ceil`, to find where it is being changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So either `Math.ceil` is not pristine and was replaced with some unexpected code or your call of `Math.ceil` is using the wrong characters. For example `1` instead of `l` or `с` instead of `c` etc. Try to retype it manually. Try to enter `Math.ceil` in the browser's console and inspect what it returns.

Comment: it's a logical stupid mistake my bad 
somehow in another file and before calling this function i used 
the ceil function like this Math.ceil=(x / y) don't know how the equal sign got there.
so it never gave me error there and the ceil function changed to be a variable somehow.